# alphanumeric sort of a region

Tags: region, sorting, lines

Assuming your buffer content is similar to this:

```
x1_y1_text_x3_y1
x1_y1_text_x3_y10
x1_y1_text_x3_y11
x1_y1_text_x3_y12
x1_y1_text_x3_y2
x1_y1_text_x3_y3
x2_y1_text_x3_y20
....
```

how to get the region sorted by last x*_y* numerically ?
I have tried different flavour of 'sort' commands but no one seems to get the expected results.

Comment: `(info "(elisp) Sorting")`

Comment: Note: The aiternate way to do this not calling native emacs sort commands directly is to go through the 'shell-command-on-region' and to call the system (unix) sort -V. 
Here is how to do it.

# Select the region to sort 
(C-u M-| shell-command-on-region) 
# sort -V

It worked for me.
Note on french keyboards you cannot reach the 'M-|' directly with Meta key because the '|' need 'Alt Gr' modifier. So the trick is to use Esc instead.
(C-u Esc-| shell-command-on-region)
sort -V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT

After I wrote the original answer (below), I realized that you probably want to sort by the 'full numbers' *. The provided buffer sort functions don't work for that, because they don't recognize the text patterns as numbers (they sort strings or fields not numbers).

So in this case you can sort it with the following command.

```lisp
(defun my-sort ()
  (interactive)
  (let (lines)
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (not (eobp))
      (push (split-string (buffer-substring-no-properties (line-beginning-position)
                                                          (line-end-position))
                          "_")
            lines)
      (forward-line))
    (setq lines (sort lines
                      (lambda (a b) (let ((x1 (string-to-number (substring (nth 3 a) 1)))
                                          (x2 (string-to-number (substring (nth 3 b) 1))))
                                      (or (< x1 x2)
                                          (when (= x2 x1)
                                            (let ((y1 (string-to-number (substring (nth 4 a) 1)))
                                                  (y2 (string-to-number (substring (nth 4 b) 1))))
                                              (< y1 y2))))))))
    (erase-buffer)
    (dolist (l lines)
      (insert (mapconcat #'identity l "_") "\n"))))
```

If you would like to use Emacs for things like this, then I would strongly recommend you to read (at least the first 8 chapters or so of) [An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/eintr.html). If you know the very basics of Emacs lisp, then I guess the command above needs no further explanation. Good luck!

END EDIT

If they are always in the same columns (if the 'first x and y' stay below 10), then you can use `sort-columns`. In your example, place mark on the 3 in the first line, then place point on 0 in the last (text) line and do `M-x sort-columns`. Read its docstring for further explanation.

Otherwise use `sort-regexp-fields` as follows with RECORD-FIELD (the first prompt)
`^.*$`
and KEY-FIELD (the second prompt)
`x[0-9]+_y[0-9]+$`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have some errors running your code.
string-to-number: `Wrong type argument: arrayp, nil`  
I feel so weird that this kind of sort (alphanumeric) is not natively embedded in emacs sort commands. 
Engineers and developers often have such kind of data regions in their files.

Comment: You probably have a line with a different pattern in your file then. Alphanumeric sort is 'embedded'. The problem is that the 'decimal place holders', are not all in the same column. Indeed, it would be nice if the definition of 'field' in the sort commands, like sort-numeric-field, could be defined a bit more flexibly. But the flexibility is anyway provided by using lisp directly. Of course, every 'engineer' is free to contribute improved sorting functions :)